# Modifying a field value in theme_preprocess_node()

Tags: theming, nodes, hooks

I have a content type (exercises) which contains a text field (field_path). In this text field I have a path to a video file.
I would like to retrieve the value of this field in theme_preprocess_node and depending on the file type (mp4, webm, avi, etc...) adapt the html formatting for rendering.
I'd also like to keep the default field twig

```
function theme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
        
   $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
      
    if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
            
        //Content type
        if($node->bundle() == 'exercices') {
                
            if($node->hasField('field_path')) {
                $path = $node->get('field_path')->getString();
                $extension = substr($path, strrpos($path, '.') + 1);
                $html = '<video controls><source src="' . $path . '" type="video/'.$extension.'">Your browser does not support the video tag</video>';
                    
                //THE FOLOWING LINE WORKS WITH DEFAULT OUTPUT , BUT IF I USE LAYOUT_BUILDER, IT DIDN'T WORK
                $variables['content']['field_path'][0]['#context']['value'] = \Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create($html);
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Do you have a better solution ?

Comment: You say you don't want to do this on field level. The problem is that on node level the last line not only depends on the field layout but also on the field type and formatter. You have to be prepared to adjust the code whenever you reconfigure the content type. BTW in a node preprocess hook don't get the node from the route, get it from $variables['node'].

Comment: Please define “better” as it pertains to how we would answer.

Comment: I guess writing a custom text format filter is "better". E.g. https://www.lullabot.com/articles/creating-a-custom-filter-in-drupal-8 - was written for Drupal 8 / CKeditor 4, but text filters should still work pretty much the same with Drupal 10 / CKeditor 5

Comment: Thanks @Hudri,
I wrote a custom field text formatter. It works fine